# Remove duplicates from a Spark JavaPairDStream / JavaDStream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm building a Spark Streaming Application which receives data via a SocketTextStream. The problem is, that the sended data has some duplicates. I would like to remove them on the Spark-side (without a pre-filtering on sender side). Can I use the JavaPairRDD's distinct function via DStream's foreach (I can't find a way how to do that)??? I need the "filtered" Java(Pair)DStream for later actions...

Thank you!

Comment: Removing duplicates on a stream is pretty hard, you can do that only in a window of data. Could you save data by key in cassandra or an other key store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .transform() method can be used to do arbitrary operations on each time slice of RDDs. Assuming your data are just strings:

```
someDStream.transform(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, JavaRDD<String>>() {
        @Override
        public JavaRDD<String> call(JavaRDD<String> rows) throws Exception {
            return rows.distinct();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The tranform / transformToPair method did it, thank you!